# Expected value of the $k$'th order statistic given that it's smaller than $\tau$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

Let $X_1,\ldots,X_n\sim U[0,1]$ be i.i.d. uniform random variables and let $X_{(k)} $ denote the $k$'th smallest variable.

Given some $\tau\in(0,1)$, what is $$\mathbb E[X_{(k)}\mid X_{(k)}\le \tau]?$$

Can we give a simple-to-use lower bound if the exact expression is not simple?

Comment: It is well-known that the order statistics of uniform has a beta distribution, therefore you are asking the mean of a truncated beta, which may involve incomplete beta I think.

Comment: @BGM - thanks for the comment. Do you know if there are any simple lower bounds on the expectation of the truncated beta distribution?